Remote plex access via synology nas using wireguard with a VPS
I am behind cgnat and port forwarding is not possible And also a static ip
I have two vps to tunnel traffic from home via vps (want to check which is faster)
On nas to connect

vps 1 wg is
[Interface]

Private Key = /0CmwhuddTndDMi2QQqQGc=
Address = 10.0.0.11/32
[Peer]
Public Key = key=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
Endpoint = vps1ip:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

vps 2 wg is
[Interface]
PrivateKey = +XgQrEKD2w=
Address = 10.0.0.20/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = GHR92uORsZvzbdd8GkSin/=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
Endpoint = vps2ip:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
vps 1 has config and iptables as follows [Interface]
PrivateKey = Gadde=
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
[Peer]
PublicKey = 2YaVQ/+k=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.11/32
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.11 --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.11 --sport 32400 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d vps1ip --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.11:32400
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 10.0.0.11 --dport 32400 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.11 -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
vps 2 has config and iptables as follows
[Interface]
PrivateKey =/7usbb0objdgeFX20=
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
[Peer]
PublicKey = kry=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.20/32
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.20 --dport 32400 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.20 --sport 32400 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d vps2ip --dport 32400 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.20:32400
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 10.0.0.20 --dport 32400 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.20 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
Actual nas internal ip is 192.168.1.10
both have net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
both have ufw disabled
both can ping each other meaning vps1 and nas , vps2 and nas
but plex is not accessible on vps2
And on vps 1 it is only accessible if I put custom url of vps1 public ip in plex settings but remote access shows no access although it runs remotely fine
Any settings which I missed or did wrong
This setup is to ensure only plex routes through the bps and rest services on nas is via isp only
Please guide

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to access plex remotely. Same settings for vps1 runs fine but not vps2 it doesn’t connect remotely to plex
